# How to access a button in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a custome toolbar in application like below there is a button call logout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo_image"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_field"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_logo_image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
            tools:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have include this toolbar in my main activity like below

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_toolbar">
    </include>
```

in my main activity I have get that toolbar like below

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
```

How can I access the button in that toolbar I want to create a onclickevent
how can i do that?

Comment: have you tried simply as `button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo_image);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findViewById` on each View. So you can use

```
Button button = (Button) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo_image);
```

But as you included the toolbar layout in your root layout, it should be even enough to use

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo_image);
```

Both should work.

EDIT: Your app_bar_toolbar.xml has a `FrameLayout` as root element, but in code you're trying to cast it to `Toolbar`. That can't work and will crash with a ClassCastException. So change your FrameLayout to a Toolbar or cast the FrameLayout correctly. Depends on your needs.

Comment: Im sorry I get the toolbar like that but app crash in there

Comment: I didnt even get the button yet

Comment: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that problem, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a toolbar, you using FrameLayout... 
use this instead

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    layout:popupTheme="@style/Toolbar.Theme">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo_image"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"></Button>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and you can use this to get the button

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 Button button = (Button) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml file for custom toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/sky"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       // here you can put your button  or any tools which you want.   

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

After that in Your activity

```
Toolbar  mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
Button btn= (Button) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo_image);


setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);  // add this line to your code.
```

and in your style.xml change `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"   to  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.crowderia.snapchat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)

Comment: error line Button btn= (Button) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo_image);

Comment: In your style.xml change parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" to parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: have u changed in your style.xml if not then change in style.xml it  should work finally

Comment: what should i changed

Comment: change in your style.xml file like this                                                                   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: its like that there is no action bar